# What to do if a question is blatantly off-topic, but you want to help

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I recently came across a new member who asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28553695/i-have-an-idea-for-a-game) question *(now deleted)*, which is blatantly off-topic, but I would like to be of help anyway. I know I can't answer, and I flagged and down voted it, and left a comment, but is there a standard way to help someone with something when the question is obviously going to be closed and removed within minutes?

Comment: Nope, no pain no gain.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's nice of you to want to help, but you have to keep in mind the goal of Stack Overflow.

While yes, Stack Overflow helps people answer their questions, the true goal of Stack Overflow is to create a database of easily accessible solutions to problems that people commonly face. **We don't just answer questions to help the current user, but to help hundreds of users down the road with the same problem.** If the question is off-topic according to the site standards, then it likely won't be helpful to others down the road.

You're much better off spending your time helping other users with on-topic questions that will be helpful to other people in the long-run, than helping to solve an obscure/inappropriate/off-topic question.

If you still do want to help, the best course of action is to comment with a tidbit of information or a link pointing the user in the right direction.